# Should an standalone Angular component have @angular/compiler as a dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

Reviewing the design of [svg-round-progressbar](https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar/)

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "^5.5.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
}
```

Does it make sense to depend on @angular/compiler?  It seems like these should be peer dependencies and not direct dependencies?

Comment: I think I agree with you. They should probably be peer-dependencies.

Comment: I think you must not have dependencies in libraires but only peer and dev dependencies. Exemple: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/package.json